# training tesseract for handwritten text

Tags: ocr, tesseract, icr

I need to identify handwritten text (icr). No need to understand arbitrary text - I am able to instruct my users to write very clearly, with separate letters and etc. However still there will be some amount of difference between any training set and the real letters.

I am hoping to train tesseract for this purpose. Has anyone tried this? Any hope in this path?

Answer (score 4):

You must have fonts similar to those handwriting letters. You may create them with any font designing tool(a sample is [here](http://fontforge.org/editexample.html)). Then you can follow the training process as described [here](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine).