# Unable to read handwritten text from form using node-tesseract

Tags: node.js, tesseract

I'm unable to read the form exactly on using node-tesseract.Only the printed text of the form is recognized and returned correctly whereas the handwritten text is returned with some special characters.

My code is,

```
var options = {
            l: 'deu',
            psm: 6,
            env: {
                maxBuffer: 4096 * 4096
            }
        };
        tesseract.process('./server/images/form.jpg', options, function (err,text) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("An error occured: ", err);
            }
            console.log("Recognized text:");
            console.log(text);
        });
```

my `input ------> OWNER Brian Dude
output------>  OW_NER ägga ] )ggé;= ‘`

here, OWNER is some text filed here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [training tesseract for handwritten text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763017/training-tesseract-for-handwritten-text)

Answer (score 3):

1. Take a look at the following papers. Both are examples that use Tesseract Training process for handwriting recognition.

[Tesseract Training for Handwritten Digit Recognition](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1003/1003.5893.pdf)

[Training Tesseract for Roman Font Handwriting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5898)

2. Check out the official Tesseract Training page.
3. The following link takes you through the Training Process, it helped me a lot.
   https://web.archive.org/web/20170820212334/http://www.resolveradiologic.com:80/blog/2013/01/15/training-tesseract
4. Use a third party GUI for Tesseract Training, it will make your life much easier. I recommend tesseract4java and jTessBoxEditor (both work on OS X)

Answer (score 0):

You can train tesseract to recognize your handwritten text.
 See [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract).